# Identifying GPRS Dynamic IP connections from the same computer

Tags: networking, dynamic, tcp, ip, gprs

I'm facing a challenging problem here that don't know how to resolve:

Context: I have a game launcher that connects to my server and if doesn't detect any cheating software on the player computer, launches the game and tells the server to allow that IP to connect to the game server.

This has many potential issues like if there are multiple players under the same IP but I make a queue in that case so all is fine until here.

Now the main problem is that I don't have control over what information sends the game, I can only modify the launcher. For this reason all is IP based as that's the only way I have to identify that a certain player is logging in and has been authorised by launcher. It goes:

- Launcher connects to Server and tells him to Allow IP A.
- Server replies: ok (save IP A)
- Launcher starts game.
- Player tries to login.
- A connection is established to the server, server checks if origin IP (IP A) is allowed to log in, if yes, go ahead.

So, the system even though far from ideal, does the job, and considering game is compiled and we cannot modify it, I couldn't think of better way.

Anyway now we come to the problem:

Certain players, when they open the launcher, all goes fine, game launches but then when player tries to login server denies connection as it comes from a different origin IP!

That broke up my mind, how can two tcp connections made within a few seconds of difference from client A to server B have a different client source IP? obviously this ruins all my system. I even tried to periodically fetch IP from sites like whatismyip to see if it was changing overtime but it wasn't the case, it seems like maybe because it goes to another port, or I don't know the reason, sometimes changes it and sometimes it doesn't.
It seems to be related to players being using tethering internet connections,as I e never seen this before on a common internet connection.

So basically, I'm not sure what could I do to identify/relate those two connections and this is a big problem as many players are unable to join my game and I cannot let them join without the launcher for obvious reasons.

My random ideas to resolve it range from bad to terrible:

- open multiple connections to server on different ports and see if that gives different source iOS
- let player connect and then do some kind of validation based on netstat check on client: when player is connected to game server I should see it there and could send that info to server, server would kick any client connected if there's no validation from launch, however, I think I would still have the problem to link both connections.
- maybe there's another way that I'm not aware of to identify this connections. Assume I have full control in server side and in launcher, but I cannot change the game server packet that does the "login" attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your assumptions (IP-based only, game/server unmodifiable), it looks like we are hitting a wall indeed..

For the moment the only thing that comes to mind is performing multiple requests to the server instead of one, and until the user finally logs in.

I mean:

- Periodically: launcher connects to server and tells him to Allow current IP. Server saves this IP and hopefully at some point you will have discovered all IPs.
- Do this in the backgound until the player is finalizing its login (or a fixed period of time)

With some luck, if you open multiple connections during the whole period of time needed to start the game and login, you will have discovered and allowed all IPs of the user. This will mitigate the issue but not eliminate it.

I'll edit this post if I think about something else.

Comment: Thank you, when I read it from someone else it doesn't seem as bad idea. It's very odd though the fact that the IP changes, I would expect also that if it changes then the currently established connection would update its ip or drop the socket, or do something about it but couldn't find an explanation other than reading that this seems to be kind of normal on gprs connectors. Anyway thank you very much

Comment: I believe IP may change frequently if you consider bad cellular situations where the device switches between 2G/3G/4G/... and if WIFI is enabled then it could lead to even more disparities. There's also features like Wi-fi+, Adaptive Wi-fi, etc which allow "seamless balancing" between mobile data and Wifi. With some advanced technologies, connections may be kept alive even when switching occurs. Connection metrics may also vary other time based on signal qualities and prioritize such or such network link and routes (hence potentially affecting visible external IP). Tethering adds to the list.